# Stack overflow error with Quicksort and median implementation

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, median-of-medians

First of all I'm just going to state that this is a homework question which I have made an extensive amount of attempts on.

I've been asked to modify quicksort in Java to set the pivot as the psuedo median of 9 values in the array using the formula `i * (n-1) /8`

I wrote a `computeMedian` method which accepts 3 integers, determines the highest, and then returns that value.

The code:

```
public static int computeMedian(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if((x >= y && x <= z) || (x >= z && x <= y)) {return x;}
        else if((y >= x && y <= z) || (y >= z && y <= x)) {return y;}
        else if((z >= x && z <= y) || (z >= y && z <= x)) {return z;}
        else { return 0; }
    }
```

I then used it in my `findPivot` method which takes the current `array, from, to` values and uses them to construct a pivot

Here is that code:

```
public static int findPivot(int[] a, int from, int to)
    {
        if(a.length <= 7)
        {
            return a[(to)/2];
        }
        else if(a.length > 7 && a.length <= 40)
        {
            return computeMedian(a[from], a[(to)/2] , a[to]);
        }
        else
        {
            int x = computeMedian(a[0 * (to) / 8], a[1 * (to) / 8], a[2 * (to) / 8]);
            int y = computeMedian(a[3 * (to) / 8], a[4 * (to) / 8], a[5 * (to) / 8]);
            int z = computeMedian(a[6 * (to) / 8], a[7 * (to) / 8], a[8 * (to) / 8]);
            return computeMedian(x,y,z);
        }
    }
```

This method is working fine for sorting any array less than or equal to size 40, but as soon as it gets larger than 40 I recieve a stack overflow error leading back to my `computeMedian` method in the `else {}` portion. I will note that `return computeMedian(a[from], a[(to)/2] , a[to]);` works in the > 40 portion if I put it there, but that is only the median of 3 values as opposed to the median of the median of 3 sets.

Currently this is how I have `findPivot` plugged into the quicksort partitioning method:

```
private static int modPartition(int[] a, int from, int to)
    {
        int pivot = findPivot(a, from, to);
        int i = from - 1;
        int j = to + 1;
        while(i < j)
        {
            i++; while (a[i] < pivot) { i++; }
            j--; while (a[j] > pivot) { j--; }
            if (i < j) { swap(a, i, j); }
        }
        return j;
    }
```

I'm pretty much stumped on why my `computeMedian` method fails to work on larger datasets. I've tried placing the `i * (n-1) / 8` values in an array via a for loop, sorting them and returning the value in the middle as well as placing the values in an array `p` and calling `computeMedian(computeMedian(p[0], p[1], p[2]), computeMedian(p[3],p[4],p[5]),...etc` and I get the same stack overflow issue but it tends to move around to different portions of my code and leading me in circles.

I can post any more snippets if anyone needs but I think my issue is right here probably.

Thanks for the help. I'm still learning and I think getting a grip on this would totally help me problem solve in the future on my own.

Here are the problem lines from the stack trace:
Line 16: `int p = modPartition(a, from, to);`
Line 18 `modSort(a, p+1, to);`
Line 23 `int pivot = findPivot(a, from, to);`

Heres my entire modSort method also:

```
public static void modSort(int[]a, int from, int to)
    {
        if(from >= to) { return; }
        int p = modPartition(a, from, to);
        modSort(a, from, p);
        modSort(a, p+1, to);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read all your text, but none of the code you added executes a recursive call as far as I can see, so they can't cause the stack overflow. What is the error message and stack trace when the error occurs?

Comment: @Andreas Bluej is telling me java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

stack trace:
`java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at BMQuicksorter.modPartition(BMQuicksorter.java:23)
 at BMQuicksorter.modSort(BMQuicksorter.java:16)
 at BMQuicksorter.modSort(BMQuicksorter.java:18)
 at BMQuicksorter.modSort(BMQuicksorter.java:18)
 at BMQuicksorter.modSort(BMQuicksorter.java:18)
`
I will add what lines those are in the original post

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint for that particular exception.

Comment: @Javier I'm sorry but unfortunately I don't exactly know what you mean by that. Could you possibly elaborate a little? Thanks

Comment: I can't see where the unbounded recursion is happening - are you sure you are executing the code you have posted? ie is it possible you are running previously compiled code, not the compiled version of what you are editing?

Comment: If you are able to debug your code. For example in Eclipse. Go to `Run` > `Add Java Exception Breakpoint...` Then enter `StackOverflowError`. Then reproduce your error and hopefully the program will be paused just at the point where error occurs. Then you will be able to examine the variables in the stack frames and look for anything abnormal.

Comment: @Javier I have my project open in eclipse but `Set Breakpoint` is grayed out on the menu to add a new breakpoint. I never use eclipse, would you happen to know what is the issue?

Comment: Nevermind. I tried reproduce the problem myself and the debugger becomes irresponsive. That memory error might make the running JVM unable to be monitored.

Comment: @Javier So what does that mean for me? Obviously I need to find a different way to find the median. I've tried to many different things, all with that same `java.lang.StackOverflow` error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced and corrected

Code added to reproduce the error ...

```
private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Generate a sample
//      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(64);
//      for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) list.add(i);
//      Collections.shuffle(list);
//      System.out.println(list);
    int[] arr = {40, 9, 2, 62, 8, 42, 46, 23, 61, 45, 63, 48, 43, 36, 33, 32, 1, 55, 7, 17, 16, 25, 5, 26, 22, 11, 56, 38, 60, 31, 58, 29, 51, 34, 24, 54, 4, 3, 30, 20, 57, 18, 50, 44, 41, 12, 59, 6, 53, 39, 37, 35, 28, 13, 14, 15, 0, 19, 49, 52, 21, 27, 47, 10};

    modSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Debugging. Setting breakpoint for `StackOverFlowError` (as suggested in comments) didn't work. So I go for a regular breakpoint at line (start of `modSort`).

For this sample data starts doing infinite recursion over `modSort` with `from=3;to=5`. For that range the pivot p=2, which seems abnormal.

I blame `findPivot(a,from,to)` method. Looks good for finding a pivot for the whole `a`, but not for a range. Trying this correction:

```
public static int findPivot(int[] a, int from, int to) {
    final int rangeLength = to - from + 1;
    if(rangeLength <= 7) {
        return a[(from + to)/2];
    } else if(rangeLength  <= 40) { // why test "a.length > 7" ?
        return computeMedian(a[from], a[(from + to)/2] , a[to]);
    } else {
        final int rangeLength_8 = (to - from) / 8;
        int x = computeMedian(a[from], a[from + rangeLength_8], a[from + 2 * rangeLength_8]);
        int y = computeMedian(a[from + 3 * rangeLength_8], a[from + 4 * rangeLength_8], a[from + 5 * rangeLength_8]);
        int z = computeMedian(a[from + 6 * rangeLength_8], a[from + 7 * rangeLength_8], a[to]);
        return computeMedian(x,y,z);
    }
}
```

Then it works fine for my example. I stop it at this point (have to get some sleep).

I think you should try to get familiar with the debugger. I think it should had been easier for you to figure it out.

Comment: You sir have helped me more than you could know.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've actually included the code and the error message for the stack overflow issue, we can help you out.

From your stack trace, we can see that the infinite recursion is *likely* the second call to `modSort`, because line 18 is repeated.

Since the only difference between that call and the incoming parameters is the 2nd parameter, I'd bet money on `p` being less than `from`.

Best way to confirm that is in insert a good old-fashioned `print` statement.

```
public static void modSort(int[]a, int from, int to)
{
    if(from >= to) { return; }
    int p = modPartition(a, from, to);
    System.out.println("from=" + from + ", to=" + to + ", p=" + p);
    modSort(a, from, p);
    modSort(a, p+1, to);
}
```

The resulting output should show a very clear pattern of what's wrong.